# Integrate facebook login with existing android app (game) in Android Studio 1.0+

Tags: android, facebook

I've spent countless hours trying to do this without asking here but I must.

Current setup:
Android Studio 1.1.0;
Facebook SDK 4.0.1

I have a game with a 3 second splash screen (because it takes that long to load the game).

I would like to put a facebook login prior to the splash screen so people can log in for score sharing or whatever.

I believe I've followed the official facebook instructions perfectly. I've done it so many times now.  I've ready every blog and watched every video.  Almost every thing I see references Eclipse so I've had to try and piece things together.

My app currently sits with facebook SDK implemented and I receive no build errors.

At one point I got the login button to show on my splash screen but only briefly and then the app would crash.

What I need to know is how and where to add the login activity and how to make it stick to the screen so the user can interact with it.  They can enter their info or decline.

Just simple facebook login for now, nothing fancy.

So much appreciated!

EDIT:

O.K. I didn't recreate the issue with the facebook screen showing up like before but. I put the following code in main.xml and what I get is a white screen for about 20 seconds and then I get the main game screen.  No flash screen appears.

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

/**
 * This is what I added
 */

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

I recreated the problem.  A "login to facebook" button shows up on the splash screen for maybe 3 seconds (the normal splash screen timeout).  It, along with the splash screen disappear and the main game screen appears. No crash.

Tried to post my logcat but it doesn't format well while posting.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if yo showed the crash log.
You haven't described the steps you've taken so far.
You need to add the app on the facebook developer console, then follow the steps to add it onto your android app as described in their docs.
If we don't know what you've done it's hard to know what's wrong.

Comment: I have no crash log because at this point I've simply imported the facebook SDK into my project, rebuilt the project and received no errors.  I'm apprehensive to start adding code because much of the doc's/instructions are not clear or outdated.  I'm looking for clear, concise instruction on what to do after importing the facebook SDK.

Comment: You wrote:
_At one point I got the login button to show on my splash screen but only briefly and then the app would crash._
How did you get to that point? Can you reproduce that and show the error?
Make sure you follow every single step here: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3)

Comment: I'm going to try and recreate right now and let you know in a few moments.

Comment: My comment is to long by 241 characters.  How to fix that?